# Iterating through rows in a sheet and comparing values in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am pretty new to this and I cannot find an answer to my question with hours of googling. My use case is this:

I have two identical sheets named "MainSheet" and "ToDo." I am able to copy a row of data from "MainSheet" to "ToDo" based on a checkbox onEdit event. In the "ToDo" sheet, I want to be able to click another checkbox (called "Made") and overwrite the original row in "MainSheet" with the new values the user provides in "ToDo." Here is what I have so far:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();[enter image description here][1]
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var originalRow = 0;
  
  // Copies Record to ToDo - If "Send To ToDo" in MainSheet is TRUE
  if(s.getName() == "MainSheet" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ToDo");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    // Sets value for column 2 to false and writes to ToDo sheet
    s.getRange(row, 2).setValue("FALSE");
    s.getRange(row, 10).setValue(originalRow); //print originalRow
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.getRange(row, 2).setValue("TRUE");
  }

  // Removes Record from ToDo - If "Made" in ToDo is TRUE
  if(s.getName() == "ToDo" && r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MainSheet");
    // Need target to find the value and overwrite to original row from MainSheet

    // Original logic
    //var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    //Test line
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(originalRow, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target); 
    s.deleteRow(row);

  }
}
```

I am aware that the code currently adds the modified row to the end of MainSheet. This was done to test the other functions in the meantime.

I figure this could be done two ways:

- Figure a way to pass the original row number back and forth
- Compare the two sheets by two values - "Name" and "Date" and calculate the row number that way.

I am not sure how to accomplish either. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I have been able to declare a variable "originalRow" and have been able to pass that value to "ToDo", however, the copyTo(target) command does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the row number, which you can do using `Range.getRow()`, this will return a `number`.

Then you need to store the value of the corresponding pair somewhere. `Name`+ `Date` not recommended, as it is not unique necessarily. Therefore I would suggest you add a column to `Main Sheet` to hold the reference to the corresponding row in the `Task.

So in your first `if()`, let's assume that in col99 there is a reference to the row of the task, then:

```
var targetRow = s.getRange(row, 99).getValue()
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetRow, 1);
```

and in your second `if()` you would need to make sure that the value is copied there.

```
target.getRange(row, 99).setValue(r.getRow())
```

#### References

- [Range.getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow)